# Using compound sql statements

Tags: sql

I am using https://try.askgit.com/ to get statistical information about a repo. Right now I need to get the number of commits over the last month(6/21), how would I do that using the sum function?

I have this statement which queries the number of commits per author for the month and then I would just sum the count column but I am not sure how to do this in SQL:

```
SELECT author_name, count(*)
FROM commits 
WHERE '2021-06-01T00:00:00.000' <= author_when AND author_when <= '2021-06-30T00:00:00.000' 
GROUP BY author_name
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

Comment: That is in SQL.  Maybe I don't understand the question.

Comment: You appear to have written SQL that accomplishes what you described. How does that SQL not meet your needs?

Comment: I think you are over complicating in your head. Your count agg function should be adequate for your needs. just name it something to make it easier to reference later. like count(*) as commitCount

Comment: the sum aggregate function is for adding a group of numbers together.

Comment: and use that name in your order by clause. I dont think that count(*) works in an orderby clause. or if it does it would not be ideal.

Comment: A SQL _compound statement_ is a `BEGIN END` block, having one or more SQL statements.

Answer (score 2):

a) Easy way is just doing two queries:

```
SELECT author_name, count(*)
  FROM commits 
 WHERE '2021-06-01T00:00:00.000'<=author_when AND author_when<='2021-06-30T00:00:00.000' 
 GROUP BY author_name ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

And then:

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM commits 
 WHERE '2021-06-01T00:00:00.000'<=author_when AND author_when<='2021-06-30T00:00:00.000'
```

b) If you *absolutely need this in one compound query, you can do:

```
SELECT author_name, count(*)
  FROM commits 
 WHERE '2021-06-01T00:00:00.000'<=author_when AND author_when<='2021-06-30T00:00:00.000' 
 GROUP BY author_name 
 UNION ALL
SELECT 'TOTAL', count(*)
  FROM commits 
 WHERE '2021-06-01T00:00:00.000'<=author_when AND author_when<='2021-06-30T00:00:00.000'
```

Having said that, please keep in mind that if you want your query to include last day of month (June 30th) you will need to use this literal: `2021-06-30T23:59:59.999`

Answer (score 2):

You don't state which RDBMS you are using.
Sample input data would be helpful.

```
--  SQL Server
SELECT author_name
, count(*)
FROM commits 
WHERE MONTH(author_when) = 6
  AND YEAR(author_when) = 2021
GROUP BY author_name
ORDER BY CASE WHEN author_name is null then 2 else 1 end, 2 DESC
```

```
--  Oracle
SELECT author_name
, count(*)
FROM commits 
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM author_when) = 6
  AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM author_when) = 2021
GROUP BY author_name
ORDER BY CASE WHEN author_name is null then 2 else 1 end, 2 DESC
```

But you also say...

> and then I would just sum the count column

Do you mean in the application after getting the results?
If you want this as an additional row in your output:

```
--  SQL Server
SELECT author_name
, count(*)
FROM commits 
WHERE MONTH(author_when) = 6
  AND YEAR(author_when) = 2021
GROUP BY ROLLUP author_name
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

```
--  Oracle
SELECT author_name
, count(*)
FROM commits 
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM author_when) = 6
  AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM author_when) = 2021
GROUP BY ROLLUP author_name
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't want the count per author, you can just do:

```sql
SELECT count(*) as Count
FROM commits 
WHERE '2021-06-01T00:00:00.000' <= author_when AND author_when < '2021-07-01T00:00:00.000'
```